# USB content - Access

Tags: usb, filesystem

I try to access USB content in my computer. I had normal access, but once I formatted it, it stopped to show in the "My Computer" menu. I opened the option "disks" on linux menu, and it appears. Then, I suppose it should be somewhere in the system, but the interface does not show up.

Please, inform which commands I should type or which softwares I should download.

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: Please help us understand. Are you trying to write to and read from a USB attached drive? If so, no additional software is required. Please clarify by clicking [edit] and make your question more clear.

Comment: Eventually post an image of your Disks interface, with your USB selected.

Comment: I already fixed the issue. The problem was on "playing" the drive on "Disks" menu option of linux distribution.